# Trouble with form api

Tags: forms

I got a problem to toggle the textfield if the ckeckbox with value 1 is checked.

```
function gkform_nameform() {
 $form['check'] = array
    (
    '#type'            => 'checkboxes', 
    '#options'         => array
      (
      1 => 'Sometext',
      2 => 'Sometext2',
      ),
    );
$form['user_name'] = array(
'#type'=>'textfield',
'#states'=>array(
    'visible'=>array(
    ':input[name="check"]'=>array('checked'=> 'options' => '1' == TRUE),
    ),
  ),
 );

$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Download')
);
return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Form API gives checkboxes names that include their options key. So your `:input` needs to be slightly adjusted to

```
':input[name="check[1]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
```

Comment: is there a goog introduction into the whole thing you can recommend? Thanx a lot!

Comment: @Jurudocs I like looking at the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) for real world documentation. It has a [whole form](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/form_example/form_example_states.inc) that shows how states works (including checkboxes)